# Get all etc accounts in Metamask (version 9.0.4)

Tags: ethereum, metamask

According to docs (https://docs.metamask.io/guide/getting-started.html#basic-considerations) I need to use **eth_requestAccounts** method. But it returns an array of ethereum addresses with one currently selected account. I have multiple accounts, so how can I get full array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, because due to privacy reasons `eth_requestAccounts` was very bad idea in the first place. It has now been disabled.